# Backwards compatibility of freezed Tensorflow models 1.15 -> 1.8

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have created a freezed model (model.pb) in Tensorflow version 1.15. When I try to do an inference with software that uses Tensorflow 1.8, I get the following error:

```
NodeDef mentions attr 'explicit_paddings' not in Op<name=Conv2D; signature=input:T, filter:T -> output:T; attr=T:type,allowed=[DT_HALF, DT_BFLOAT16, DT_FLOAT, DT_DOUBLE]; attr=strides:list(int); attr=use_cudnn_on_gpu:bool,default=true; attr=padding:string,allowed=["SAME", "VALID"]; attr=data_format:string,default="NHWC",allowed=["NHWC", "NCHW"]; attr=dilations:list(int),default=[1, 1, 1, 1]>; NodeDef: featMapG/unet_down_0/conv1/conv = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], explicit_paddings=[], padding="SAME", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true](map/TensorArrayStack/TensorArrayGatherV3, featMapG/unet_down_0/conv1/weights/read). (Check whether your GraphDef-interpreting binary is up to date with your GraphDef-generating binary.).
```

As I do not have access to the inference code, that is I cannot upgrade tensorflow there, is there a way to "downgrade" a freezed model to be usable with Tensorflow 1.8?